# Reference URLs with LaTeX and the chicago style manual?

Tags: bibliographies, chicago-style

I'm writing a paper with LaTeX and trying to get the `\bibliographystyle` to work correctly.

I'm using the `chicago` manual reference style. In my `.tex` file a have declared:

```
\usepackage{chicago}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
```

And I use BibDesk for Mac to generate my `.bib`-files. It works, but I have one problem. URLs are not referenced in the right way, according to the Chicago Manual. http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide.html says it should look something like this:

> 1. “Google Privacy Policy,” last modified March 11, 2009, hxxp://www.google.com/intl/en/privacypolicy.html.
> 2. “McDonald’s Happy Meal Toy Safety Facts,” McDonald’s Corporation, accessed July 19, 2008, hxxp://www.mcdonalds.com/corp/about/factsheets.html.

But LaTeX only gives me something like this:

> - Bank, N. (2011, 04). Bruken av kort
>     og nettbank øker fortsatt.

It does not include the URL to the site, even though I have defined the URL in my `.bib`-file.

How can I get this to work correctly, with the correct style? Thanks for all answers.

PS: I don't HAVE to use the Chicago Reference Style, I can use others, if that makes things simpler, but I read somewhere that It's a good style for writing engineering papers (computer science). (If you have other suggestions, that is also welcome).

**Edit. Additional info:** This is the bib-file that BibDesk generates for a webpage:

```
 @webpage{norges-bank-okning,
   Author = {Norges Bank},
   Date-Added = {2011-04-02 18:39:21 +0200},
   Date-Modified = {2011-04-02 19:19:30 +0200},
   Keywords = {web},
   Lastchecked = {02.04.2011},
   Month = {04},
   Title = {Bruken av kort og nettbank {\o}ker fortsatt},
   Url = {http://www.norges-bank.no/templates/article____16691.aspx},
   Urldate = {02.04.2011},
   Year = {2011}}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change to [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), you can use [biblatex-chicago](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago); here's a little example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mybiblio.bib}
@article{S, 
  author = "Spivak, M.",
  year = "1969",
  title = "Unknown",
  url = "http://www.spivak.org"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{mybiblio.bib}

\begin{document}

\autocite{S}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

EDIT: using the bib entry in the question's EDIT, I used the following code (note that I used the `organization` field instead of the `author` field and changed the `urldate` format as required by `biblatex`):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mybiblio.bib}
@online{norges-bank-okning,
   organization = {Norges Bank},
   Date-Added = {2011-04-02 18:39:21 +0200},
   Date-Modified = {2011-04-02 19:19:30 +0200},
   Keywords = {web},
   Lastchecked = {02.04.2011},
   Month = {04},
   Title = {Bruken av kort og nettbank {\o}ker fortsatt},
   Url = {http://www.norges-bank.no/templates/article____16691.aspx},
   Urldate = {2011-04-02},
   Year = {2011}}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mybiblio.bib}

\begin{document}

\autocite{norges-bank-okning}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and obtained the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thnx. But I get an error when I try your example. `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago-notes-df/biblatex
-chicago.sty:39: Package keyval Error: 14 undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.39 \ProcessOptions*
                     
? `

Comment: My example code compiles OK in my system, so perhaps you are using some outdated package(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked. I defined the entry as @misc and in the Howpublished field I put \url{www.url.com}.

This worked great.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{chicago}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
```

And my .bib-entry like this.

```
@misc{norges-bank-okning,
    Author = {Norges Bank},
    Date-Added = {2011-04-02 18:39:21 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2011-04-02 21:16:52 +0200},
    Howpublished = {\url{http://www.norges-bank.no/templates/article____16691.aspx}},
    Keywords = {web},
    Lastchecked = {02.04.2011},
    Month = {04},
    Title = {Bruken av kort og nettbank {\o}ker fortsatt},
    Url = {http://www.norges-bank.no/templates/article____16691.aspx},
    Urldate = {02.04.2011},
    Year = {2011}}
```

Comment: `url` is a non-standard BibTeX field, and thus support for that field is often hit-and-miss, which is why it doesn't display in your original example. Unfortunately, if when the next version of BibTeX is released, the url field becomes supported, your current work-around may result in the url being displayed twice in future documents.